# how to return Observable with filter operator?

Tags: filter, rxjs, observable

If I write the code like following, it returns Subscription object.

```
return this.http.get(url, { responseType: 'text' }).pipe(
    filter((data: any) => data.value === 'Apple')
);
```

But is there a way to return Observable? Actually, I have read this [Type 'Subscription' is missing the following properties from type 'Observable<StringMap<any>>'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57727125/type-subscription-is-missing-the-following-properties-from-type-observablest) which is the most relevant and already provides solution. but still can't come up with good solution for it, for quick implementation could you give some information about it?

Comment: That *does* return an observable.

Comment: I do not think so, if I use that way, it says that 
Type 'Subscription' is missing the following properties from type 'Observable<any>': _isScalar, source, operator, lift, and 6 more.ts(2740)

Comment: That would be true if you also had `.subscribe(...)`, but that's not in the question. Give a [mcve].

Comment: yes, you are right, it returns observable, sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

As @jonrsharpe said, that does return an Observable.
The question should be asked with a working sample (preferred on stackblitz).

Have a look here: https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/filtering/filter

filter returns an Observable.

However, if you were to subscribe to your returned Observable, then the Subscription would meet the expected value.
Source: https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/guide/subscription